# SQL Related Query

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables, named "A", "B" and "C", with the columns "Name", "Roll_No" and "Age". I want to locate a row referencing from "Roll_No" columns, but I don't know the in which table desired row exists. I need a SQL statement which will return the row along with respective table name.

Comment: This is not the way to ask a question here.

provide DDL/DML and expected sample result

Comment: Also probably not relevant for this question you should always add the tag for the DBMS you are using. Postgres, Oracle, DB2, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you need to specify WHERE clause one time:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
   (SELECT Name, Roll_No, Age, 'A' AS TableName
      FROM A
     UNION
    SELECT Name, Roll_No, Age, 'B'
      FROM B
     UNION
    SELECT Name, Roll_No, Age, 'C'
      FROM C) Tbl
WHERE Roll_No = [value]
```

Comment: the only problem with this is it has not better performance in compare with the version which does not use subqueries and multiple selects

Comment: Thank You Vardan Shahinyan Sir

Answer (score 1):

use `union` as below:

```
select Name, Roll_No, Age ,'A' as table_name from A where Roll_No=--the value
union 
select Name, Roll_No, Age ,'B' as table_name from B where Roll_No=--the value
union 
select Name, Roll_No, Age ,'C' as table_name from C where Roll_No=--the value
```